# How to clear a buffer to 1.0 instead of 0.0 in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

Using `glClear()` you can set the buffer specified by the parameter to `0.0`. This is useful say if you want pixels not covered by models to be black. Because `vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` results in black.

But for the depth buffer, clearing means to set it to the maximum value `1.0` since you don't want pixels not covered by models to have the depth `0.0` which is the camera's position but to have the depth `1.0` which means as far away as possible.

So how can I clear the depth buffer to `1.0` or come over this issue in another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use:

- `glClearColor(r, g, b, a)` to set the color of `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`
- `glClearDepth(depth)` for the depth buffer
- `glClearStencil(stencil)` for the stencil buffer

Alternatively, you can use `glDepthFunc` to change the way the depth buffer is tested.

Comment: Since what I have isn't an actual depth buffer but a color buffer using `glClearColor` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `glClearDepth` where you can specify what to clear the depth buffer to. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearDepth.xml however I think `glClear()` clears the depth buffer to 1.0 by default.

> glClear sets the bitplane area of the window to values previously
>   selected by glClearColor, glClearDepth, and glClearStencil

As `glClearDepth` states

> Specifies the depth value used when the depth buffer is cleared. The initial value is 1.